# ML Retraining project

Tags: python, machine-learning

Tear me to shreds.

The class RandomForestRetrainer will be used to retrain a machine learning algorithm. It has functionality for taking in a directory containing malware or benignware files and splitting them into training and testing sets, creating statistics from these files, creating concatenated mw/bw training/testing stat files, balancing the mw count with bw count via a reduction algorithm, and finally sending them to the ML classifier for training.

p.s. let me know if you want to see code from the other classes

```
import os
import datetime

from retraining.StatsFile import StatsFile
from retraining.Dataset import Dataset
from retraining.Partitioner import Partitioner
from retraining.GridBasedBalancingRandom import GridBasedBalancingRandom
from retraining.Classifier import Classifier
import config

class RandomForestRetrainer(object):

def __init__(self, previous_mw_dataset=None,
                   previous_bw_dataset=None):

    self.mw_datasets = []
    self.bw_datasets = []
    self.malware = None
    self.benignware = None

    self.data_folder = self._initialize_data_folder()
    self.balancer = GridBasedBalancingRandom()
    self.classifier = Classifier(self.data_folder)

    if previous_mw_dataset is not None:
        if type(previous_mw_dataset) is not Dataset:
            raise TypeError("one or more arguments not of type Dataset")
        self.mw_datasets.append(previous_mw_dataset)

    if previous_bw_dataset is not None:
        if type(previous_bw_dataset) is not Dataset:
            raise TypeError("one or more arguments not of type Dataset")
        self.bw_datasets.append(previous_bw_dataset)

def add_malware_dataset(self, path):
    if type(path) is not str:
        raise TypeError("path must be a string")

    dataset = self._build_dataset_from_path(path, is_malware=True)
    self.mw_datasets.append(dataset)

def add_benignware_dataset(self, path):
    if type(path) is not str:
        raise TypeError("path must be a string")

    dataset = self._build_dataset_from_path(path, is_malware=False)
    self.bw_datasets.append(dataset)

def malware_count(self):
    return self._count_files_in_datasets(self.mw_datasets)

def benignware_count(self):
    return self._count_files_in_datasets(self.bw_datasets)

def concatenate_stat_files(self):
    if not self.mw_datasets and not self.bw_datasets:
        raise RuntimeError("No datasets have been added")

    mw_train, mw_test, bw_train, bw_test = self._create_concatenated_stat_files()

    self.malware = Dataset(mw_train, mw_test, is_malware=True)
    self.benignware = Dataset(bw_train, bw_test, is_malware=False)         

def balance_datasets(self):
    if not self.malware and not self.benignware:
        raise RuntimeError("Concatenated stat files have not been created")

    self.balancer = GridBasedBalancingRandom()
    self.balancer.set_malware_dataset(self.malware)
    self.balancer.set_benignware_dataset(self.benignware)
    self.balancer.balance()

def train(self):
    if not self.malware and not self.benignware:
        raise RuntimeError("Concatenated stat files have not been created")

    self.classifier.add_training_data(self._get_malware_training_stats_path())
    self.classifier.add_training_data(self._get_benignware_training_stats_path())
    return self.classifier.train()

def run_test_metrics(self):
    if not self.malware and not self.benignware:
        raise RuntimeError("Concatenated stat files have not been created")

    self.classifier.add_testing_data(self._get_malware_testing_stats_path())
    self.classifier.add_testing_data(self._get_benignware_testing_stats_path())
    return self.classifier.test()

'''
Private
'''

def _initialize_data_folder(self):
    data_folder = os.path.join(config.BASE_DATA_FOLDER,
                                    datetime.datetime.now().isoformat())

    if not os.path.isdir(config.BASE_DATA_FOLDER):
        os.makedirs(config.BASE_DATA_FOLDER)
    os.makedirs(data_folder)
    return data_folder

def _build_dataset_from_path(self, path, is_malware):
    partitioner = Partitioner(path, self.data_folder)
    partitioner.process()
    training = StatsFile(partitioner.training_stats_file)
    testing = StatsFile(partitioner.testing_stats_file)
    return Dataset(training, testing, is_malware)

def _count_files_in_datasets(self, datasets):
    training = 0
    testing = 0
    for dataset in datasets:
        training += dataset.training_stats.get_count()
        testing += dataset.testing_stats.get_count()
    return training, testing

def _create_concatenated_stat_files(self):
    mw_train_file = open(self._get_malware_training_stats_path(), 'w')
    mw_test_file = open(self._get_malware_testing_stats_path(), 'w')
    bw_train_file = open(self._get_benignware_training_stats_path(), 'w')
    bw_test_file = open(self._get_benignware_testing_stats_path(), 'w')

    for dataset in self.mw_datasets:
        self._write_stats_to_file(dataset, mw_train_file, mw_test_file)

    for dataset in self.bw_datasets:
        self._write_stats_to_file(dataset, bw_train_file, bw_test_file)

    mw_train_file.close()
    mw_test_file.close()
    bw_train_file.close()
    bw_test_file.close()

    mw_train = StatsFile(self._get_malware_training_stats_path())
    mw_test = StatsFile(self._get_malware_testing_stats_path())
    bw_train = StatsFile(self._get_benignware_training_stats_path())
    bw_test = StatsFile(self._get_benignware_testing_stats_path())

    return mw_train, mw_test, bw_train, bw_test 

def _write_stats_to_file(self, dataset, training_file, testing_file):
    training_file.writelines(dataset.training_stats.get_stats())
    testing_file.writelines(dataset.testing_stats.get_stats())

def _get_malware_training_stats_path(self):
    return os.path.join(self.data_folder, config.CONCATENATED_MALWARE_TRAINING_STATS)

def _get_benignware_training_stats_path(self):
    return os.path.join(self.data_folder, config.CONCATENATED_BENIGNWARE_TRAINING_STATS)

def _get_malware_testing_stats_path(self):
    return os.path.join(self.data_folder, config.CONCATENATED_MALWARE_TESTING_STATS)

def _get_benignware_testing_stats_path(self):
    return os.path.join(self.data_folder, config.CONCATENATED_BENIGNWARE_TESTING_STATS)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As reviewers, it's helpful if we have more context on what the code does in order to provide the best review possible. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My knowledge of machine learning is a rounding error, so I can’t assess the accuracy of the code. I can provide some feedback on the general programming quality:

- There are no comments or documentation. None, nada, zilch. This program would be significantly improved if there were some comments or docstrings, so that I could tell what the code was supposed to do. Explaining the motivation behind the code will make it much easier to read, review and maintain.
- You have a lot of checks of the form:

  ```
  if type(foo) is not bar:
      raise TypeError("foo is not of type bar")
  ```

  One potential risk here is that you don’t cater for inheritance. Suppose I have a subclass of `bar` called `girder`. If I pass in a variable of type `girder`, it will raise a TypeError, even though it probably supports the same interface as `bar` and is probably fine.

  The alternative is to use

  ```
  if not isinstance(foo, bar):
      raise TypeError("foo is not of type bar or of a subclass of bar")
  ```

  This [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549854) explains the difference between `type()` and `isinstance()` quite well. I’m not saying you should definitely use one or the other, but unless I had a good reason I’d usually use `isinstance()`.
- You add the `balancer` attribute to the class in the `balance_datasets()` method. This is sometimes frowned upon – even if you initialise it to None, it’s good to declare all your attributes up front in the constructor. It makes it easier to find out what sort of attributes your class might have.
- The one docstring in the file (“private”) is incorrect. Strictly speaking, these are *protected* methods, not private.

  Python doesn’t have access control for methods and attributes. The rules are enforced by convention, and everybody is expected to behave sensibly (“we’re all consenting adults”). https://stackoverflow.com/a/797814
- The `_initialize_data_folder()` method is subject to a race condition. If the base data folder doesn’t exist, but is created between your if statement and the `os.makedirs()` call, you’ll throw an OSError.

  A better approach is to pass the `exist_ok` method to `os.makedirs()`, which will suppress the error if the folder already exists.
- You have a bunch of methods that start with the word “get”. It would be more Pythonic to decorate these with @property and use them as attributes.
- In the `_create_concatenated_state_files()` method, you should really use `with` when opening files:

  ```
  with open(self.malware_training_stats_path, 'w') as mw_train_file,
       open(self.malware_testing_stats_path, 'w') as mw_test_file:
      for dataset in self.mw_datasets:
          self._write_stats_to_file(dataset, mw_train_file, mw_test_file)
  ```

  This ensures that the file is closed correctly, even if the body throws an exception, and ensures the close() call cannot be forgotten or omitted.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @alexwlchan posted another idea:

In `_create_concatenated_stat_files` the paths are created twice and the
methods to create them seem a bit superfluous.  A simpler approach would
just assign the paths to variables and possibly later reuse the name
from the file objects instead:

```
class RandomForestRetrainer(object):
    def _data_path(self, path):
        return os.path.join(self.data_folder, path)

    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.malware_training_stats_path = self._data_path(config.CONCATENATED_MALWARE_TRAINING_STATS)
        self.benignware_training_stats_path = self._data_path(config.CONCATENATED_BENIGNWARE_TRAINING_STATS)
        self.malware_testing_stats_path = self._data_path(config.CONCATENATED_MALWARE_TESTING_STATS)
        self.benignware_testing_stats_path = self._data_path(config.CONCATENATED_BENIGNWARE_TESTING_STATS)
        ...

    def _create_concatenated_stat_files(self):
        with open(self.malware_training_stats_path, 'w') as mw_train_file,
             ...
            for dataset in self.mw_datasets:
                self._write_stats_to_file(dataset, mw_train_file, mw_test_file)
            ...
        ...
        return StatsFile(mw_train_file.name), ...
```

---

IMO collecting the results in a list looks cleaner, but YMMV:

```
def _create_concatenated_stat_files(self):
    ...
    return [StatsFile(x.name) for x in [mw_train_file, mw_test_file, bw_train_file, bw_test_file)
```

Because if the code is structured in a way that this collection of
filenames is available all the time, e.g. even stored in a
dictionary or so, manipulating all of them at the same time
becomes easier, like in this `return` statement.